# Spring Security Logout not clearing securitycontext from all the threads having it

Tags: session, spring-security, tomcat7, logout

We are using spring security with tomcat container for our application.

Suppose a user hits some request to the server. Now while this request is being processed at the server (assuming it's taking some time), we do logout from another tab.

Now what happens that after logout, last session gets invalidated, but when the first request is served, it creates a new session and spring security populates context from ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy to this new session.

So in a way even after doing logout, user is still logged into the application.

Is there something out of box which we are missing, can help us fix this.
Atleast somebody please help in direction whether writing a custom securityContextHolderStrategy is good enough or do we need to something else.